# $|x - 1| = 1 - x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

$$|1 - x| = 1 - x$$
$$\iff -(x - 1) = 1 - x \text{ or } x - 1 = 1 -x$$
$$\iff -x + 1 = 1 - x \text{ or } 2x = 2$$
$$\iff 0 = 0 \text{ or } x = 1$$

The $0 = 0$ is bothering me. This answer does not make any sense. What mistake did I do here?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The condition $-x+1 = 1-x$ holds for every real number. But the condition $|x-1|=-(x-1)$ only holds if $x-1 \leq 0$. So you need both $x\leq 1$ and the vacuous condition in the first "branch" case. Similarly, you really need a "and $x-1\geq 0$" in the second branch, which you got lucky that it was implied by the other condition.

Comment: $0=0$ always holds. You should be explicit about the assumptions that lead to these equations. The equality will hold for all $x$ that lead to $0=0$.

Comment: In summary, you get that either $x\leq 1$ ( from the first case) or that $x=1$ (from the second). An easier way to solve this is to note that your equation really says that the absolute value of $a=x-1$ is $-a$, and this happens if and only if $a\leq 0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin :   Thank you, I understood the concept.

Comment: @MartinR : Thanks. I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: You probably made the mistake of not drawing a diagram ...

Comment: The logic error is in the 2nd line.  Replace "$-(x-1)=1-x$"  with "$0\le  -(x-1)=1-x$", which is equivalent to $x\le 1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simplify equations, you're really relating propositions. For example, $x+1=y+1$ is a proposition about those two variables.

When we "subtract 1 from both sides to get $x=y$, we're creating a new proposition, and by the rules of algebra, we know that the new one is true if and only if the old one is.

If, by a sequence of such propositions that are logically equal, you end up at one that is always true, like $0=0$, that makes every one in the chain true. If you end up with $1=0$, then it makes the whole chain false.

That example is simple. Sometimes, one proposition turns into a compound one: $x^2=1$ turns into $x=1$ **OR** $x=-1$.

In the case of absolute value, you have to be pretty careful. The proposition $|x|=a$ is true if and only if $(x<0\: AND\: -x=a) OR (x\ge 0\: AND\: x=a)$. That is four propositions in one.

I think the comments have already pointed out where exactly you went wrong. I hope this answer helps clarify what it means to get to 0=0.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the absolute value function better now.